# I tried to call in c++ to function from C file to my cpp file but getting some errors:

Tags: c++, c

I have a

```
c++ project dll type .
```

I added/created to this project a new item/file called it ENCODER.c 
In the ENCODER.c i have some functions like:

```
void init()
{
}

void start()
{
}
```

Now i added/created a new header file called it: ENCODER.h

In this one i did:

```
namespace Encode
{
    class Encode
    {
    public:
    static __declspec(dllexport) void init();
    };
}
```

Then in the cpp file i did:

```
#include <stdexcept>

using namespace std;
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "targetver.h"
#include "ENCODER.h"


extern "C" {
    void  myinit()
    {
        Encode::Encode::init();
    }

}
```

In the cpp file i want that

```
Encode::Encode::init(); this init()
```

will do/activate the init() function i have in the C file !!

Now after doing all that i'm getting two errors:

1. LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static void __cdecl Encode::Encode::init(void)" (?init@Encode@1@SAXXZ) referenced in function _myinit
2. LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

Comment: I tried now to change the H header file code to: namespace Encode
{
 extern "C" {
    class Encode
    {
    public:
 static __declspec(dllexport) void init();
 };
    }
} but same errors. Maybe the problem is that in the header file i did void init(); ?

Answer (score 4):

First you need to `declspec(export)` the whole class, but it's more complex than that as you need to `declspec(import)` when using the class.  Use the following macro and define `BUILDING_MYLIBRARY` when building the library (and ensure it's undefined when *using* the library)

```
#ifdef BUILDING_MYLIBRARY
    #define MYLIBRARY_EXPORT __declspec(export)
#else
    #define MYLIBRARY_EXPORT __declspec(import)
#endif
```

And then use it like this:

```
class MYLIBRARY_EXPORT Encode
{
    ...
};
```

Next ensure that any C functions that can be seen by C++ are declared `extern "C"` to turn off *name mangling* (the technology C++ uses to allow function overloading).  So create a header (`ENCODER.h`) file for the C functions as follows, and include the header file in any C++ implementation file that wishes to use these functions:

```
#pragma once

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
{
#endif

void MYLIBRARY_EXPORT init();
void MYLIBRARY_EXPORT start();

#ifdef __cplusplus
}    // extern "C"
#endif
```

and then implement these functions in a separate implementation (`ENCODER.c`) file (the use of `MYLIBRARY_EXPORT` is optional; it depends if you want to expose them from your `.dll`).  When implementing them you don't need the `extern "C"` or the `MYLIBRARY_EXPORT` as long as the compiler has seen the header file, so include it:

```
#include "ENCODER.h"

void init()
{
    ...
}

void start()
{
    ...
}
```

Suggestion: Choose better names! The `start()` function already exists in the C runtime library, so how about `initEncoder()` and `startEncoder()`?

Comment: trojanfoe i need to clarify some things. The #ifdef BUILDING_MYLIBRARY all this part i put it in the c file the header file or the cpp file on top of them ? Second this class MYLIBRARY_EXPORT Encode i use it in the cpp file ? I tried to use it and in any place i did i get an error on the MYLIBRARY_EXPORT the error is: unkown attribute "import" then in the end what is the ENCODER.c file did you mean a new c file ot create or the one i already have now with the functions ?

Comment: Yes the `BUILDING_MYLIBRARY` macro definition should be in a single header file and included everywhere there are symbols to export from the `.dll`.  If needs to be part of the class and function *declaration* (i.e. in the header file), not the *definition* or *implementation* file.